# Google Analytics Reporting API TOS and Caching

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I have a client website with Google Analytics installed. The client would like to have a carousel widget of sorts created that will appear in the header area on all the pages of the website.  This widget will display the top 10 most visited pages on the website for a given timeframe.

I'm looking to create a Google API authentication piece on the backend of the website and setup the necessary Google Analytics Reporting API call to obtain the required info.  My thought was that this call could be made once daily or weekly and the results saved so that the widget could access this information as required without having to make a new API request each time.

This seems like a reasonable setup but I'm unclear if this will violate Google API's TOS.

https://developers.google.com/terms

The TOS reads ...

*e. Prohibitions on Content
Unless expressly permitted by the content owner or by applicable law, you will not, and will not permit your end users or others acting on your behalf to, do the following with content returned from the APIs:
Scrape, build databases, or otherwise create permanent copies of such content, or keep cached copies longer than permitted by the cache header;*

With the above in mind, who is the content owner that I would need to get permission from?  Is my client the content owner of their analytics data or is Google?

Comment: Define "client website" is this a website you own or one you have created for a client (customer)

Comment: @DaImTo "client website" is referring to a website we've built for for our client. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is my client the content owner of their analytics data or is Google?

Your client is owner of their Google analytics data.

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo.  I thought the same but a member of the legal team thought Google was.  You wouldn't happen to know of any additional documentation to support your assessment or if there's away to specifically ask Google in this regard?

Comment: I would check the TOC or TOS you agree to when you create a Google and or Google Analytics account.   When you create an account anything stored in your account is owned by you.